# Turn on subsection numbering in memoir

Tags: numbering, memoir, sectioning

It seems that the `memoir` class automatically avoids numbering subsection headings. Chapter and section titles are numbered, but subsection headings contain only the subsection name, and are not prefixed by the subsection number. Why is this the case, and more importantly, how do I turn subsection numbering back on?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The correct way to do this, specifically for `memoir`, IMO, is to use

```
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
```

Why?:

- It's a higher-level command --- `\setcounter` is somewhere in the bowels of memoir/LaTeX
- It's semantic --- saying "subsection" is hopelessly more meaningful than saying "2"
- It's practical --- it persists across `\mainmatter`

Answer (score 36):

The counter `secnumdepth` controls "[t]he level number of the least significant sectional unit with numbered headings" (Lamport, *LaTeX: A document preparation system* , p. 176). The `memoir` class sets `secnumdepth` to 1 (section), so you should change this to 2 (subsection). Alternatively, you may use the memoir command `\setsecnumdepth`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}% alternative A
% \setsecnumdepth{subsection}% alternative B

\begin{document}

\chapter{bla}

\section{blubb}

\subsection{foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried setting that in the preamble, but it hadn't worked -- it turned out that `\mainmatter` resets `secnumdepth`. Now that I know what to look for, the memoir documentation states that calling `\maxsecnumdepth` in the preamble sets the numbering level for `\mainmatter`.

Comment: Just a minor note. If you want the subsection to appear in the TOC as well, you should issue the `\maxtocdepth{subsection}` command.

Answer (score 20):

change the `secnumdepth`, using the `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}`
the following table may help.

```
Command                            Level        Comment
------------------------------------------------------------------------
\part{part}                        -1       not in letters
\chapter{chapter}                   0       only books and reports
\section{section}                   1       not in letters
\subsection{subsection}             2       not in letters
\subsubsection{subsubsection}       3       not in letters
\paragraph{paragraph}               4       not in letters
\subparagraph{subparagraph}         5       not in letters
```

Comment: `memoir` has an easier interface such that people do not need to remember those numbers