# Subsections in the ToC when using memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, memoir

Following on from [Turn on subsection numbering in memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/subsection-numbers-in-memoir), having numbered my subsections, how can I get them to appear in the ToC?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\maxtocdepth` Sets which headings level should show up in the table of content so if I understand you right you want to write:

```
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
```

Comment: I usually only use `\settocdepth{subsection}`, I have never had to mess with `\maxtocdepth`

Comment: @daleif: I believe `\maxtocdepth` is for the preamble, and defines the default that will be set by `\mainmatter`.

Comment: I just looked, `\mainmatter` only touch `secnumdepth`. The difference between `\settocdepth` and `\maxtocdepth`

Answer (score 4):

Use `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`. The value is similar to `secnumdepth`'s.

Comment: Memoir has a better interface, mapping names to numbers. No new users know that 2 equals subsection

Comment: @daleif: Unless they read the manual.

Comment: @TH.: (subsection = 2) is what I call useless information. I only have ~ 1 terabyte in my brain... (:-)