# Subsection numbers with memoir + frontmatter

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, front-matter

I've just tried to use \frontmatter with memoir class for the first time and everything works fine except for some weird detail. When I add \frontmatter and \mainmatter commands, the numbers of subsections disappear in the ToC and also in the subsection titles themselves. The code is the following:

```
...
\chapterstyle{veelo}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
...
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\include{abstract}
\include{acknowledgement}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\include{chap0_intro}
\include{abbrev}
\mainmatter
\include{chap1_somi}
\include{chap2_simulation}
...
```

ToC looks like this:

[image]

Why and how can I get them back while keeping the matter-commands?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I've found an answer to this question eventually: in the comment to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3329/3897: I should use `\setcounter{maxsecnumdepth}{3}`, not `secnumdepth`.

Or, even better, `\setsecnumdepth{subsection}` as said in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33458/3897.

Comment: Actually the correct `memoir` command is: `\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}`.

Comment: @AlanMunn I've just updated the answer :)