# Need index to display custom description environment item name

Tags: hyperref, memoir, indexing, counters, description

I am trying to accomplish something like in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63643/make-index-entries-refer-to-number-selected-paragraphs) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20894/make-index-entries-refer-to-something-other-than-the-page-numbers).

I have several authors contributing solutions to problems that are numbered using an externally imposed scheme, which I handle via the `description` environment. I wrap each author's name in `\index{}` and need the printed index to display the problem number as it appears in the external scheme. Right now I'm using the report document class, but could be persuaded to change.

I picked up a way to capture the external numbering using a modified `\ref{}` command from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167/how-does-one-set-custom-labels-for-description-lists), but have not been able to get the index to display other than just the counter value.

For example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{desccount}
\newcommand{\descitem}[1]{%
\item[#1] \refstepcounter{desccount}\label{#1}
}
\newcommand{\descref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\descitem{1B.1} by \index{Smith}
\descitem{1B.3} by \index{Jones}
\descitem{1C.1} by \index{Smith}
\descitem{1E.11} by \index{Burton}
\end{description}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I would like the resulting index of the document to be

```
Burton   1E.11  
Jones    1B.3  
Smith    1B.1, 1C.1
```

with `hyperref` filling in the hyperlinks appropriately. The closest I've come is to use the `memoir` document class and include a `\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\specialindex{\jobname}{desccount}{#1}}` but this simply returns the value of `desccount` and not the external numbering scheme. In the example given, the output I would get is

```
Burton    4  
Jones     2  
Smith     1, 3
```

which is not quite what I want. How can I have the index return the argument of `\descitem` instead of the page number or the value of `desccount`?

Comment: This seems more like a glossary, than an index. I'd look into the `glossaries` package.

Comment: @egreg, you may be right, but I'm not sure how to do this using the `glossaries` package either. I tried using the `xindy` option with `\GlsAddXdyLocation{descref}` but still only got the results of `desccount` and not the external numbering system. Do you have any specific feedback on what to do with the `glossaries` package in this case?

Comment: @Brian: If you're still interested in a solution, see my possible answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution with `glossaries` and writing 'arbitrary' text labels to the `.aux` file which are used in turn to provide problem number using `\getrefnumber` (package `refcount`)

The underlying `desccount` counter was used to provided the relevant entries for the new glossary `provider`.

There might be better setups for `\descitem`, but this was given by the O.P. I changed it a little bit to `\descitem[provider name]{Number}`.

I kept the old `\descitem` macro on purpose, but commented it!

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[nomain,savenumberlist=true]{glossaries}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\writetextlabel}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\newlabel{description::\number\value{desccount}}{{#1}{\thepage}{}{desccount.\number\value{desccount}}}% 
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{desccount}
% Here is the 'original' \descitem command. 
%\newcommand{\descitem}[2][]{%
%\item[\protect\hypertarget{#1}{#1}]\refstepcounter{desccount}\writetextlabel{#1}
%}

\NewDocumentCommand{\descitem}{om}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
  \item[\protect\hypertarget{#2}{#2}]\refstepcounter{desccount}\writetextlabel{#2} by \gls{#1}%
  }{%   
  \item[\protect\hypertarget{#2}{#2}]%
  }%
}


\newglossary[prl]{provider}{pri}{pro}{Providers of solutions}[desccount]
\newglossaryentry{Smith}{%
  type={provider},
  name={Smith},
  description={Smith has provided some of solutions},
}

\newglossaryentry{Jones}{%
  type={provider},
  name={Jones},
  description={Jones has provided other solutions},
}

\newglossaryentry{Burton}{%
  type={provider},
  name={Burton},
  description={Burton was a lazy guy}
}



\makeglossaries


\newglossarystyle{providerdesc}{%
\setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
  \begin{longtable}{lp{0.6\glsdescwidth}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}%
%
\renewcommand{\glsnumberformat}[1]{\protect\hyperlink{\getrefnumber{description::##1}}{\getrefnumber{description::##1}}}% Change to use the textlabel
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
  \bfseries Author & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Solutions provided \\
  \hline
  \endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
  \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
  & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
  & \space ##2  \tabularnewline
}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\descitem[Smith]{1B.1}
\descitem[Jones]{1B.3} 
\descitem[Smith]{1C.3}
\descitem[Burton]{A5.6}
\end{description}

\clearpage

\begin{description}
\descitem[Smith]{A.1}
\descitem[Jones]{A3} 
\descitem[Smith]{45.B} 
\descitem[Burton]{6.E} 
\end{description}


\setglossarystyle{providerdesc}
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]