# Numbering of subsections using memoir

Tags: sectioning, numbering, memoir

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turn on subsection numbering in memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/turn-on-subsection-numbering-in-memoir)

I'm writing a thesis using **memoir** as my class. I've noticed it only includes numbering on chapters and sections, not subsections. However **I would like numbers on my subsections etc**. I have tried the `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` but it doesn't seem to work :/ Can anyone help me?

Comment: In my experience, the `memoir` class does indeed automatically number subsections.  Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to better illuminate your problem.

Comment: No it does not, by default ony chapter and section. Use `\setsecnumdeph{subsection}\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}`, there is a similar macro to control the depth of the toc

Comment: With `memoir`, subsections aren't numbered by default, but `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}` or `\setsecnumdepth{subsection}` should work. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/turn-on-subsection-numbering-in-memoir

Comment: Silly me.  I was thinking of the `report` class.

Comment: Thank you. `\setsecnumdepth{subsection}` works better since `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}` is reset by `\mainmatter`.